# Swift How to make protocols imported imported from another module accessible outside of current module

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, module, ios-frameworks

Using swift I created a framework Common that contains functions and protocols I use repeatedly to cut down on code reuse.

Common.framework

```
public protocol CommonProtocol {}
```

I than created a framework that I want to share with others which includes some classes that extends CommonProtocol and passes CommonProtocol in response to some function calls.
Sharable.framework

```
public class Sharable : CommonProtocol {
    func getCommon() -> CommonProtocol
}
```

Unfortunately when I attempt to use Sharable.framework in a Project I get there error:

> Swift Compiler Error
> Use of undeclared type 'CommonProtocol'

Does anyone know how to make the protocol visible to Modules that use the Sharable.framework?

I am copying the frame Common.framework in the Copy Files step to Destination Frameworks (there was no noticeable change when I made it Shared Frameworks)

If possible I would prefer to only make certain protocols from Common.framework visible through Sharable.framework and I don't want to force my users to import multiple frameworks if I can avoid it.